# Circular window

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have this fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/oeuc8L9y/2/

If you click the background the coordinates where you clicked get centered.

Is it possible to make the pointer events only work inside the hole?
Since I'm using an image for the ring the whole thing blocks the pointer-events but if I set it to `pointer-events: none;` I can click trough the ring too.

This is good.

[image]

This is bad.

[image]

I assume a way would be to get the pixel coordinate and calculate if it's inside the hole but I feel like that would only work for a specific screen size and it'd break if resized.

```js
tooltip_X = $("#x-coords");
tooltip_Y = $("#y-coords");

$("#background").on("mouseover", (e) => {
    showTooltip(e);
});
$("#background").on("mousemove", (e) => {
    updateCoords(e);
    moveTooltip(e);
});
$("#background").on("mouseout", (e) => {
    hideTooltip(e);
});
$("#background").on("click", (e) => {
    move(e);
    updateCoords(e);
});

function showTooltip(e) {
    $("#tooltip").css("display", "block");
}

function hideTooltip(e) {
    $("#tooltip").css("display", "none");
}

function moveTooltip(e) {
    var left = 0;
    var top = 0;

    if (e.pageX + $("#tooltip").width() + 10 < document.body.clientWidth) {
        left = e.pageX + 10;
    } else {
        left = document.body.clientWidth + 5 - $("#tooltip").width();
    }

    if (e.pageY + $("#tooltip").height() + 10 < document.body.clientHeight) {
        top = e.pageY + 10;
    } else {
        top = document.body.clientHeight + 5 - $("#tooltip").height();
    }

    $("#tooltip").offset({ top: top, left: left });
}

function updateCoords(e) {
    var mouse_x = e.clientX - $("#background").offset().left;
    var mouse_y = e.clientY - $("#background").offset().top;
    $("#x-coords").text(Number.parseInt(mouse_x));
    $("#y-coords").text(Number.parseInt(mouse_y));
}

function move(e) {
    var mouse_x = e.clientX - $("#background").offset().left;
    var mouse_y = e.clientY - $("#background").offset().top;

    var new_x = 0;
    var new_y = 0;

    if (mouse_x < 250) {
        mouse_x = 250;
    }
    if (mouse_y < 250) {
        mouse_y = 250;
    }
    if (mouse_x > 1670) {
        mouse_x = 1670;
    }
    if (mouse_y > 950) {
        mouse_y = 950;
    }

    new_x = -(mouse_x - 250);
    new_y = -(mouse_y - 250);

    $("#background").css("margin-top", new_y);
    $("#background").css("margin-left", new_x);
}
```

```css
#container {
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 100;
}

#ring {
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 100%;
    max-height: 500px;
    max-width: 500px;
    z-index: 90;
    pointer-events: none;
}

#lens {
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid red;
    /*
  something to make it round
  */
    z-index: 80;
    pointer-events: none;
}

#background {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1920px;
    height: 1200px;
    background-image: url("https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/197542.jpg");
    z-index: 80;
    outline: 5px dotted purple;
    outline-offset: -5px;
}

#tooltip {
    position: absolute;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background: #ffffcc;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
    color: black;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<html>
    <head> </head>

    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <img id="ring" src="https://pngimg.com/uploads/circle/circle_PNG26.png" alt="Lens Ring" />
            <div id="lens"></div>
            <div id="background"></div>
            <span id="tooltip"> Div Coords (<span id="x-coords"></span>,<span id="y-coords"></span>) </span>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can add a listener to resize event and recalculate when resize occurs

Comment: Did you manage to figure it out, or can I give you an answer?

Comment: @s.kuznetsov Of course you can, even if I had found an answer on my own I'll never not want other peoples answers.